# ASP.NET vNext with typescript

Tags: npm, typescript, nuget, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2015

I have downloaded the `Visual studio 2015 RC` to test the new `ASP.NET vNext`. Now I'm trying to build a `MVC project` with typescript.

I found that in vNext uses the following dependencies (correct me if I'm wrong):

- Nuget for backend dependencies
- Bower for client-side dependencies
- Npm for client-side build dependencies

But who have to fetch definitions for typescript(*.d.ts like jquery.d.ts...)?

From the things I wrote above, it would have to be done by `Bower`, which does not have any typescript definitions. Similarly, `Nuget` does not include any typescript definitions that can be added to the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TSD Manager is a npm package.  However understand your explicit categorization of what tool is used for what dependency doesn't exist.  VS 2015 provides some templates but they are just that.   Don't like grunt, gulp or bower and want to use a different task runner and package manager well you can use them as well right out of the box (as long as it can be installed by npm).  Some web developers just use npm for everything instead of using npm & bower.

To specifically answer your question you can install the TypeScript Manager by adding `"tsd": "0.6.3"` to your `packages.json` file and doing a package restore.

Comment: I'm trying to find something like `best-practise`. Thank you! That what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

> But who have to fetch definitions for typescript(*.d.ts like jquery.d.ts...)?

TSD for typescript definitions: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/tsd

Comment: I know where to find those typescript definitions. In visual studio below 2015 nuget package manager was loading/updating those typescript definitions files. The question is who have to manage those files in visual studio 2015